# Is there a German word for computationally secure?

Tags: single-word-request, technical-terminology

*This is mainly intended for German cryptographers and I think since the topic is really specific it's more relevant to ask this here than in a German language section.*

Cryptography is mainly based on English sources and most of the time I use the English terms anyways, but especially for 'computationally secure' there is not even a rough approximation in German. How do you translate that?

The closest I can get would be "berechnungssicher gegen Brute-Force-Angriffe" but that's not exact.

Comment: My shot at this would be (and I had this problem before): *"sicher gegen alle effizienten Angriffe"*

Comment: At the moment I'm using half German, half English in my lectures. "sicher gegen effiziente Angriffe" sounds good, but a letter frequency analysis is an efficient attack too, and no one would say that a substitution cipher is secure against that.

Comment: my shot is roughly equivalent to the more formal *"secure against all polynomially bounded adversaries"* (which is the basically the long form of *"computationally secure"*) and in this context *nobody would ever say that a substitution cipher is computationally secure*, so the term covers substitution (and all classical) ciphers as well. If you want to express *"secure against brute-force attacks"*, try *"sicher gegen alle {naiven; trivial offensichtlichen} Angriffe"*.

Comment: What about "kryptographisch sicher"?

Comment: German Wikipedia [uses the terms](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beweisbare_Sicherheit#Asymptotische_Sicherheit) _asymptotische Sicherheit_ and _komplexitätstheoretische Sicherheit_. I like the latter term in particular.

Comment: BTW: If your question is off-topic on one site (e.g. [Crypto.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/)) but a subset of the audience of that site may be helpful / interested in answering the question, you can always just identify their chat (e.g. [*The Side Channel*](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/784/the-side-channel)) and leave a line or two there.

Comment: I wouldn't use "computationally secure" for a substitution cipher either. (Unless you're talking about it being indistinguishable from a PRP, but then frequency analysis is out of scope)

Comment: @SEJPM: Ein Angriff, der misslingt, kann schlecht effizient genannt werden. "Sicher gegen systematisches Durchprobieren" vielleicht.

Answer (score 3):

The business dictionary defines [computationally secure](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/computationally-secure.html) as "... cannot be broken with the current computer technology within a period short enough to be practicable."

That suggests "mit heutigen Mitteln unangreifbar".

Comment: mglw. auch _Stand der Technik, Wissensstand, Kenntnisstand, Technikniveau, verfügbarer Rechenleistung_ o.ä. – oder ugs. _praktisch unknackbar_

Answer (score 0):

Translating "computationally secure" directly into german is not easily possible, because it seems to be lacking a word, that something is possible, but not feasible.

However, you could use "secure against all polynomially bounded adversaries" as an equivalent intermediate step for "computationally secure" and thereby construct the phrase

> sicher gegen (alle) effiziente(n) Angriffe

where "effizient" is equivalent, by convention, to "polynomially bounded" and "Angriffe" is used to catch the more (in this case) algorithmically used "adversaries".

As your comments suggest you may be looking for something that says, that a substitution cipher is secure against brute-force, then you need a different qualifier for "Angriffe", such as "naive" or "trivial offensichtlichen", resulting in the phrase:

> sicher gegen (alle) naive(n) Angriffe
>
> sicher gegen (alle) trivial offensichtliche(n) Angriffe

with the latter having a rather neutral connotation and not excluding anything that would need more than five seconds thought.

Note further, that using the term "computationally secure" paired with "subsitution cipher" is not a good practice, because those ciphers are by themself *very* often not computationally secure in the standard definition.

Answer (score 0):

> Sicher gegen systematisches Durchprobieren.

Unklar ist natürlich, ob der Angreifer mit einem Haushaltsrechner angreift, einem Botnetz, zusammengeschalteten Grafikkarten oder der orchestrierten Macht der NSA.